# How to handle gemset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am new to Rails. Each time I open a new terminal in Linux, it tells some gem is missing. But I have installed the gem in the same folder already in different terminal. So could anyone please advise how can I fix the problem.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific. What have you done (step by step) and what error exactly do you get.

Answer (score 0):

Rails gemsets can be a bit tricky. It can be global, rails-version specific or project specific. I guess you are using global gemset. In your project terminal you can run

```
gem list
```

to see the gems that is available in your project. If you don't find one in the list, make sure you have it in your gemfile. and then again run

```
bundle install
```

Comment: Rails doesnt have gemsets. RVM has gemsets.